# A certain amount=particular amount?

Tags: synonyms

Does **a certain amount** means **small quantity**? And what if you are asked to find a *synonym* of it. Do you say:

> Artists need **a certain amount** of freedom to express their creativity. (Small quantity)

Synonym:

> Artists need **a particular amount** of freedom to express their creativity. (Also, Small quantity)

Why is that this "certain amount" does not come up when I googled it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A certain amount" implies that some specific, fixed amount exists without explicitly saying *what* that amount is. This fits with the word's [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/certain) and with common idiomatic use among native speakers.

Compare "he would like some apples" with "he would like a certain number of apples". In the first case, any number of apples greater than 1 will likely meet the requirements. In the second case, there is some specific number of apples that the person wants, but the number is not yet expressed.

"A particular amount" or "a specific amount" would be suitable substitutes.

There is often an implication that the amount is small, but I would not say that "a small amount" would be a synonym.

Comment: Now that you've convinced me, I've taken back my downvote. I'm a person of certain reasonability :)

Answer (score 0):

"a certain amount of" is synonymous with "some" (how much exactly, we don't know). Actually, "a certain amount of" is used to refer to an indefinite amount. What is certain is that any such amount does not need to be small.

- Artists need a certain amount of freedom to express their creativity.

can then be paraphrased as:

- Artists need some freedom to express their creativity.

I don't think "a particular amount of" is a good synonym, since such a partitive will refer to a **specific** amount. Such specificity is absent in "certain" which, as I explained, is understood as **indeterminate** or **indefinite**.

Comment: I disagree. "Certain" does indicate something definite; it just does not express what that definite thing is.

Comment: @Tashus Well, MacMillan (https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/a-certain) does define "a certain amount of" as "some", and I don't think "some" carries any specificity.

Comment: I would argue that "a certain amount" could be synonymous with "some amount" rather than just "some", i.e. an amount of something exists that meets some requirements, but that specific amount may not be known. It is a way of using indefinite language to refer to something that is definite, such as saying "that thingamajig".

Comment: Compare "He would like some apples" with "He would like a certain number of apples". In the first case, any number of apples greater than 1 will likely meet the requirements. In the second case, there is some specific number of apples that the person wants, but the number is not yet expressed.

Comment: Similarly, "some people" refers to an indefinite number of people, but "some person" refers to only a single person, but a person whose identity may not be known.

Comment: @Tashus You are right. I seem to have been confused between "specific" and "specified". "some freedom" would be equivalent to "any amount of freedom". However, see that "certain" with other nouns does sound like "some", for example *Artists need certain freedom*.

Comment: Even in your example *Artists need certain freedom*, the point of using the word "certain" is to specify that some particular minimal amount of freedom is required, whereas "some" really just means "more than zero".

Comment: +1 *Certain* ***can*** refer to something specific, but it doesn't need to. I completely agree with your paraphrase here. It means more than no freedom—but it doesn't necessarily imply a known amount of freedom beyond that. "Artists required a certain amount of freedom." "How much?" "I don't know. I just know they need some." That's a perfectly reasonable dialogue.